# Issues while configuring collectd with java (GenericJMX) plugin to fetch weblogic data

Tags: weblogic12c, collectd

Actual behavior:
Does not connect to weblogic server, throws an error and does not load java plugin:

java plugin: cjni_create_jvm: JNI_CreateJavaVM failed with status -1.

[2017-05-04 04:23:34] java plugin: cjni_thread_attach: cjni_create_jvm failed.
[2017-05-04 04:23:34] java plugin: Configuration block for `GenericJMX' found, but no such configuration callback has been registered. Please make sure, the`LoadPlugin' lines precede the `Plugin' blocks.
[2017-05-04 04:23:34] java plugin: cjni_init: jvm == NULL
[2017-05-04 04:23:34] Initialization of plugin`java' failed with status -1. Plugin will be unloaded.

Steps to reproduce

Enable Java plugin after making the below changes to the collectd.conf:,

JVMArg "-Djava.class.path=/scratch/gbuora/u00/app/ora_fmw/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wljmxclient.jar:/scratch/gbuora/u00/app/ora_fmw/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wlclient.jar:/opt/collectd/share/collectd/java/collectd-api.jar:/opt/collectd/share/collectd/java/generic-jmx.jar -Djmx.remote.protocol.provider.pkgs=weblogic.management.remote -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/scratch/gbuora/u00/app/ora_fmw/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/connectTrust.jks -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder -Djavax.net.ssl.identityStore=/scratch/gbuora/u00/app/ora_fmw/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/connectIdentity.jks-Djavax.net.ssl.identityStore=/scratch/gbuora/u00/app/ora_fmw/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/connectIdentity.jks -Djava.naming.security.principal=weblogic -Djava.naming.security.credentials=welcome123 "
LoadPlugin "org.collectd.java.GenericJMX"

```
<MBean "garbage_collector">
  ObjectName "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,*"
  InstancePrefix "gc-"
  InstanceFrom "name"

  <Value>
    Type "invocations"
    Table false
    Attribute "CollectionCount"
  </Value>

  <Value>
    Type "total_time_in_ms"
    InstancePrefix "collection_time-"
    Table false
    Attribute "CollectionTime"
  </Value>
</MBean>

<MBean "memory">
  ObjectName "java.lang:type=Memory"
  InstancePrefix "memory-"

  <Value>
    Type "memory"
    Table true
    Attribute "HeapMemoryUsage"
    InstancePrefix "heap-"
  </Value>

  <Value>
    Type "memory"
    Table true
    Attribute "NonHeapMemoryUsage"
    InstancePrefix "nonheap-"
  </Value>
</MBean>

<MBean "memory_pool">
  ObjectName "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,*"
  InstancePrefix "memory_pool-"
  InstanceFrom "name"

  <Value>
    Type "memory"
    Table true
    Attribute "Usage"
  </Value>
</MBean>


<Connection>
  Host "localhost"
  ServiceURL "t3://localhost:8001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime"
  Collect "memory_pool"
  Collect "garbage_collector"
  Collect "memory"
</Connection>
```

Restart collectd.

Comment: After making changes to the properties, i am able to load the java plugin, but now i am getting a different error:  GenericJMXConfConnection: Creating MBean server connection failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]

Comment: After making somemore changes, now i am getting the error " GenericJMXConfConnection: Creating MBean server connection failed: java.io.IOException".
JVMArg "-Djava.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"
 ServiceURL "service:jmx:iiop://localhost:8001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime"

Answer (score 0):

renamed the localhost in the service:jmx:iiop url with complete hostname. the  issue got resolved.